# how can i make a span element in this line of php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, html

I what to put a span element for $term['nodes'] 
I have tried to put after bracket and  between  but nothing works for me

`if (isset($term['nodes'])) {
      $term['name'] = $term['name'] . ' (' . $term['nodes'] . ')';
    }`

here is the all functin

```
    function bootstrap_taxonomy_menu_block($variables) {
  $tree = $variables['items'];
  $config = $variables['config'];

  $num_items = count($tree);
  $i = 0;

  $output = '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">';
  foreach ($tree as $tid => $term) {
    $i++;
    // Add classes.
    $attributes = array();
    if ($i == 1) {
      $attributes['class'][] = '';
    }
    if ($i == $num_items) {
      $attributes['class'][] = '';
    }
    if ($term['active_trail'] == '1') {
      $attributes['class'][] = 'active-trail';
    }
    if ($term['active_trail'] == '2') {
      $attributes['class'][] = 'active';
    }

    // Alter link text if we have to display the nodes attached.
    if (isset($term['nodes'])) 
{ 
    $term['name'] = $term['name'] . ' (<span>' . $term['nodes'] . '</span>)'; 
}

    // Set alias option to true so we don't have to query for the alias every
    // time, as this is cached anyway.
    $output .= '<li' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . l($term['name'], $term['path'], $options = array('alias' => TRUE));
    if (!empty($term['children'])) {
      $output .= theme('taxonomy_menu_block__' . $config['delta'], (array('items' => $term['children'], 'config' => $config)));
    }
    $output .= '</li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';

  return $output;
}
```

i what this for the bootstrap cdn class , i have move the function on template.php , of drupal theme , but the span element is in plain text in browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (isset($term['nodes'])) 
{ 
    $term['name'] = $term['name'] . ' (<span>' . $term['nodes'] . '</span>)'; 
    echo $term['name']; // To see the output
}
```

Comment: i have tried this solution but this is duplicate my term['nodes'] - i will edit the question , with my all function , [link](http://webstral.com/service) , i what to put this span only becaus i what to use the bootstrap cdn class , an i what to make a badge for that term['nodes']

Comment: Then just delete the echo, and It won't duplicate

Comment: yes i have delete the echo , but still the span element sens to be in plain text , can i post a link with the page to see the result ? [link](http://webstral.com/service) <- here is the link , in the left i have a menu that i what to make a nav with boostrap cdn class, the span element will be use only for the counter of the nodes , to make badgests of it